# Corona SDK with Graphic 2.0 position not working

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have upgraded my Corona SDK version to 2013.2076 (with Graphic 2.0). But now my background images are not working and the app is crashing.

```
local background = display.newImageRect("/bg.png", 570, 360 )
background:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
background.x = display.contentCenterX ; background.y = display.contentCenterY
gameGroup:insert(background)
```

It is working perfectly in previous version of Corona SDK. I am not being able to identify the issue. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the release of Corona Build 2013.2076, the `setReferencePoint` is deprecated.
You can use

```
background.anchorX = 0.5 ; 
background.anchorY = 0.5 ;
```

For more information about `anchors` see

http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/transform-anchor.html

See examples here

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/anchorX.html

and

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/anchorY.html